# Device permissions

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I rooted HTC Desire 526 5.0 with kingroot Apk and it says that my device is not giving the root permission so what do I do to fix that please help me thank you dee

Answer (score 0):

flash with SuperSU..and grant the application root access